# Windows Authentication MVC [Authoize(Roles = "two words")] Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am developing an Intranet site for my company and I am using Windows Authentication. My issue is when I try to add a Role that has two words separated by a space I get the Windows Security Modal pop-up asking for my username and password. However, if the Role only has one word, it works perfectly.

Sample Group names in Active Directory: "Human Resources", "Project Managers", "Education" for my example below.

Example that works:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Education")]
```

Examples that do not work:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Human Resources")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Project Managers")]
```

I have tried:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Human Resources")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Human_Resources")]
[Authorize(Roles = "HumanResources")]
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\Human Resources")]
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\HumanResources")]
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\Human_Resources")]
```

Besides going into Active Directory and changing my user groups to not include spaces, is there anything that I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Two things I learned. You have to log off and log back into you domain account if you added yourself to a group. Windows Auth was looking at a cached version of the roles I belonged in. Domain Admins is a group that will not allow this [Authorize(Roles = "Domain Admins")] in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas to fix this:

1. No need to restart just deny yourself access via web.config e.g. 
   `<deny users="*" />` reopen browser to get 401, remove deny statement and restart browser and roles cache is refreshed. **but Also:**
2. Check and double check and check again "role names" are correct
3. prefix with domain\ roles="domain\role"
4. Role with space work fine when using:

c#

```
public static class AppRoles
{
    public const string Manager     = @"domain\App Manager";
    public const string Admin       = @"domain\App Admin";
}

[Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.Admin)] 
public class MyAbcController : Controller
{
    //code
}
```